# Java File - can you use readUTF to read a string from a text file?

Tags: java, file, io, binary

Java File - can you use readUTF to read a string from a text file?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you use readUTF to read a string from a text file?

Answer: No.

A text file contains (by definition<sup>1</sup>) just human readable text.

The `readUTF` methods read a string that has been encoded as a 2 byte non-textual representation of the string length followed by UTF-8 encoded characters.  If the format (in the file) doesn't match the above, you are liable to get invalid strings or exceptions.

You won't find a string representation like that in a purely text file.  The string length would show up in a text file as a couple of "garbage" characters.

The `readUTF` methods are intended for reading strings that were written by the corresponding `writeUTF` methods.

---

<sup>1 - If you (the OP) disagree with this definition, then please explain precisely what you mean by "a text file" in the context of this question.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can if the file was written to using `writeUTF`.  `writeUTF` first writes a `short` (denoting the length of the `String` about to be written) and then writes the actual `String`.  As long as your file is in that format, then it will work perfectly.

If you're wondering exactly how to use it, read the documentation of [`DataInputStream#readUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF--) for reading and [`DataOutputStream#writeUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) for writing.

Example (in Java 10):

```
try (var stream = new DataInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt")))) {
    var text = stream.readUTF();
}
```

Comment: If the file was written by `writeUTF()` it isn't a text file.

Comment: @EJP I disagree; text file is a broad term and is not limited to plain text.